# What is the method to determine the XOR placing in CRC code with random generator

Tags: digital-logic, crc

I'm reading a lot of different tutorials about how to implement CRC gates for different generators, But I couldn't understand the method.
For example, for the following generator, this example states that the following gate generates the valid message output
[image: c]

E.g what would be the circuit, if the generator was `x^3+x+1` instead of `x^3+x^2+1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the generic case (CRC-n) as:
[image: CRC-n]

Here, when \$a_k=0\$, the **AND** gate where it is connected to, results in 0, what makes the **XOR** gate a *pass thru*. When \$a_k=1\$, the **AND** gate connects the feedback loop to the **XOR** gate, as expected.

Now, for your particular case, \$n=3\$, and CRC-3 defined as \$X^3+X^1+1\$ you have:
[image: CRC-3]

What is equivalent to:

[image: CRC-3 Equivalent]

Answer (score 1):

The answer supplied by guga is wrong.

You either assume \$h(x) = x^n + a(1) x^{n-1} +..... + a(k) x + 1\$, or you just start using the same formula order supplied with the answer. But you start with \$a(k)\$ in the feedback loop between \$x0\$ and \$x1\$. It's worth noting that \$h(x)\$ isn't the generator function of the code's parity \$g(x)\$, it's the coefficient function of the code's parity, while \$g(x) * h(x) = x^n +1\$, the logical circuit for \$g(x)\$ is different.

Here's a source [CRC encoding](https://caslab.ee.ncku.edu.tw/dokuwiki/_media/research:caslab_2001_jnl_01.pdf) page 447 (third page of the PDF) has the circuit based on the generator function's circuit and page 448 (4th page of the PDF) has the circuit for the coefficient function's logical circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the XOR/delay element (flip flop) interconnect scheme you showed is correct, just move the left most XOR operation to the right 1 delay element.